# How to import Google Tests xml results to VSTS

Tags: c++, azure-devops, googletest

We use Google Test (gtest) for tests in our C++ based solution.
We build it in VSTS to run on Windows.
When we run test .exe it produces **test_detail.xml** file with results of the test run:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="1152" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="8.57" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="testTrim" tests="10" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.041">
    <testcase name="trimEmptyString" status="run" time="0" classname="testTrim" />
...
```

How to import this file to VSTS?

It would be ideal if gtests are recognized and displayed on build Summary page, even if it's just pass\fail, no details of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the format of **test_detail.xml** (report produced by gtest) is **JUnit**, so it's very easy to import into VSTS, as described here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-java