# How to Publish GoogleTest Results in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, googletest

I've been reading through the documentation for [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for Azure Pipelines and looking at the [GoogleTest XML format](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#generating-an-xml-report) and as far as I can tell, none of the supported formats match, but I'm not positive.

Is there a cross platform solution for publishing the test results for a GoogleTest in an Azure Pipeline?

Comment: The format of test.xml (report produced by gtest) is JUnit. You can refer to this [How to import Google Tests xml results to VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241171/how-to-import-google-tests-xml-results-to-vsts)

Comment: It would be great if there was some documentation on either link I posted above that said that.

Comment: This is mentioned in your second link:The report is based on the junitreport Ant task. If you want Microsoft documentation to show this, you can submit a feature request in our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site . Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of test.xml (report produced by gtest) is JUnit. This is mentioned in your second link:The report is based on the `junitreport` Ant task.

After knowing that the format of the report is JUnit, according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/java?view=azure-devops), it is easy to import report into azure devops.

For example,building with Ant, add the following snippet to your `azure-pipelines.yml` file.

```
steps:
- task: Ant@1
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    buildFile: 'build.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
```

For details,you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241171/how-to-import-google-tests-xml-results-to-vsts). If you want Microsoft documentation to show this, you can submit a feature request in our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site . Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.